# Avoid importing column as float

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column which I want to convert to a string consisting of only 12 digits. For this, I use the below snippet:

```
# Convert the column to a 12 digit string
df['MY_COLUMN'] = pd.to_numeric(df['MY_COLUMN'], errors='coerce')
df['MY_COLUMN'] = df['MY_COLUMN'].astype(str).str.zfill(12).str.slice(0, 12)
```

However, my output looks something like this:

```
16072934175.0
16026886931.0
16089115785.0
16095735607.0
16086482684.0
```

How could I obtain the same thing but without the final .0?

Expected output:

```
016072934175
016026886931
016089115785
016095735607
016086482684
```

Comment: What are the original values in df['MY_COLUMN']?

Comment: You can use only df['MY_COLUMN'].str.zfill(12)

Comment: They are the values I am getting but without the final .0

Comment: @Phoenix I want first to get rid of the rows that do not contain all characters numeric

Comment: Use the `downcast='integer'` argument to `to_numeric()`

Comment: Do you have null values in this column?

Comment: @Barmar it does not change at all after downcast='integer'

Comment: @Phoenix I could have if the conversion pd.to_numeric is not valid since I am coercing the errors.

Comment: maybe drop NaNs, then cast to int?

Comment: @enke could be an option, but I'd be more keen on not throwing out the NaN values if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason why you could not convert it because it is float even after using `.astype(str)`, you can give it a try and check the type of the column after `.astype(str)`. But `zfill(12)` expects a `str` type to work not a `float`.

You can try this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'c': ['160c','33','c44','99','dd'],
     'd': [1]*5
    }
)

df = df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df['c'], errors='coerce').notna()]
df['c'] = df['c'].astype('str').apply(lambda x: x.zfill(12))

#output
```

[image]